# Como deixar uma linguagem "Default" no GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Este é um projeto feito em *Ruby*, porém, como utilizei o [Twitter BootStrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), ele apresenta como linguagem predominante o *JavaScript*, pois é a linguagem que predomina no repositório. Tem como eu forçar para que a linguagem padrão seja o **RUBY**?

**Links para o repositório**
https://github.com/luizpicolo/agenda-universitaria-ruby-sinatra

Answer (score 7):

O GitHub tenta inferir a linguagem do repositório através da bibliotecas [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist). Infelizmente até onde sei não existe um fluxo automatizado para trocar a linguagem de um repositório.

No topo do repositório do Linguist está escrito:

> Language Savant. If your repository's language is being reported
>   incorrectly, send us a pull request!

Então talvez valha a pena mandar um pull request para o pessoal da biblioteca explicando que essa é uma aplicação Ruby feita com Twitter BootStrap. Talvez seja uma questão de adicionar alguns linhas a mais do [vendor.yml](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/vendor.yml) dessa biblioteca para remover os diretórios contendo JavaScript específicos desse framework.

Um ponto importante é que o vendor.yml já contém uma regex para excluir o bootstrap:

```
# Bootstrap minified css and js
- (^|/)bootstrap([^.]*)(\.min)?\.(js|css)$
```

Antes de mandar um *pull request* é importante verificar se a regex está incompleta / com algum problema ou se você está usando uma estrutura de diretórios que foge do padrão vide comentário do @utluiz. Talvez uma alternativa seja mover os scripts para a pasta `bootstrap` por exemplo.

Uma outra alternativa seria clicar no botão "Contact A Human" a partir da tela de ajuda sobre [repositórios marcados com a linguagem errada](https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language) e ver como o pessoal do GitHub responde.

Se nada disso funcionar você pode ainda migrar seu repositório para outro serviço. Particularmente migrei todos os meus repositórios para o [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). Esse é um serviço da Atlassian com repositórios Git e Mercurial; inclusive, além de repositórios Open Source, para times com até cinco membros os repositórios privados também são gratuitos. Você pode [importar](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project) facilmente seus repositórios do GitHub e editar a linguagem do projeto no menu administrativo. Os principais contras para mim são ausência de algo similar aos [Gists](https://gist.github.com/) e o fato de ser um serviço menos conhecido (apesar de usuários do GitHub poderem logar normalmente com suas contas), mesmo assim estou plenamente satisfeito com a mudança e hoje só uso o GitHub para contribuições eventuais em projetos Open Source de terceiros.

Comment: Se alguém mandar um pull request específico sobre um projeto, acredito que eles vão pedir para você adequar sua estrutura aos padrões definidos por eles.

Comment: De qualquer forma, +1 por citar o BitBucket. Eu uso e recomendo. No GitHub não podemos ter projetos privados.

Comment: utluiz, não conheço os mantenedores, mas vou atualizar a resposta com esse fato :).

Answer (score 4):

Você não pode fazer isso manualmente.

Segundo a [página de ajuda do GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language), eles usam uma biblioteca chamada Linguist, a qual determina a linguagem predominante nos arquivos.

Entretanto, como a mesma página citada indica, você pode excluir arquivos de terceiros desta verificação colocando as dependências em determinados locais que o Linguist não olha.

Isso está definido no aruqivo [vendor.yml](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/vendor.yml) do Linguist, contendo diversos padrões de exclusão para muitos dos casos mais comuns:

- jQuery e outras biblitecas javascript
- Pastas como `cache` e `dependencies`
- Arquivos `README` e de licença
- E muito mais...

Enfim, você só precisa olhar o arquivo e colocar suas dependências nos locais adequados, se não não estiverem.

Comment: O `vendor.yml` é na verdade parte do linguist e não do seu repositório. Alterações a ele devem ser feitas como *pull requests* à biblioteca e afetaria a todos os repositórios do github. Ou entendi errado?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Está certo, é isso mesmo. Vou ajustar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Solução vide :
https://github.com/github/linguist

Considere o arquivo ".gitattribute" do seu projeto insira em algum local do arquivo a sintaxe:

Para todos os arquivos da pasta ou diretório
SeuProjeto/NomeDoDiretorio/* linguist-vendored

ou
SeuProjeto/NomeDoDiretorio/*.js linguist-vendored

ex: ProjetoSite/Script/* " ou /*.js" linguist-vendored

Para um ou mais arquivos específico da pasta ou diretório
SeuProjeto/NomeDoDiretorio/nomeArquivo.js linguist-vendored

Isso vai vedar o contato de stack do GitHub de considerar na contagem do projeto.

obs: em uma determinada Pasta ou diretório se quiser colocar um tipo de arquivo ou algum arquivo de sua escolha na contagem é só inserir ao final do comando 
"arquivo.tipo linguist-vendored=false"
exemplo:
Scripts/* linguist-vendored
contador.vb linguist-vendored=false

para um ou mais arquivos que deseje.