# Especificar linguagem DEFAULT no Github?

Tags: php, git, github, default

Tenho um projeto em PHP no github.
Porém o mesmo, definiu a linguagem principal do projeto como CSS...
Há algum meio de mudar a linguagem padrão de forma manual? Algum arquivo editável.. etc. Obrigado.

Comment: Onde você viu esse esquema de "linguagem principal"?

Comment: Cara da uma olhada neste post, acho que isso pode te ajudar! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2009/como-deixar-uma-linguagem-default-no-github

Comment: No Overview dos repositórios.